# Elements in literal objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

If I use this javascript:

```
var test = {
    vars: {
        $mydiv: $('#myDiv')
    },

    HideDiv: function () {
        this.vars.$mydiv.hide();
    }
} 

test.HideDiv();
```

Then it fails. Do I really have to do like this:

```
var test = {
    vars: {
        mydiv: '#myDiv'
    },

    HideDiv: function () {
        $(this.vars.mydiv).hide();
    }
} 

test.HideDiv();
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) JavaScript isn't Java. 2) Javascript needs some comma. 3) you console shows you syntax errors, use it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be solved by looking at the console.


Comment: Sry guys ... it's not the comma problem .. I just forgot the commas in this example.

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6qauQ/

Comment: Well, then it's probably that the code should be executed in a ready callback.

Comment: If I do it in fiddle ... and do this ... console.log(this.vars.$mydiv); .. I get a '[div#myDiv...' but if I do it in my MVC, I get '[context: document...'. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test` object needs to be created after the DOM has been loaded in order for jQuery to know that `#myDiv` exists:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = {
        vars: {
            $mydiv: $('#myDiv')
        },

        HideDiv: function () {
           this.vars.$mydiv.hide();
        }
    }
    // ...
});
```